# The middle elements in my array are not being swapped

Tags: assembly, mips

I have been trying to resolve this issue for the last five hours.  I have to compare the first index with the last index.  If the first < last, they are to be swapped.  This works fine if my array has five elements or less.  Anything larger and the swapping stops after two iterations.  What am I doing wrong?

My subroutine that reverses the array:

```
ReverseArray:
    add $s0, $a0, $0

    li  $t2, 1
    la  $s0, array
    li  $s1, 4
    sub $s2, $t0, 1         #lines 177 - 180 finds the last index of the array
    mult    $s2, $s1
    mflo    $s2
    add $t3, $s2, $s0

    swap:
        lw  $t5, 0($s0)
        lw  $t4, 0($t3)     #stores the element of last index into $t4

        sle $t1, $t5, $t4
        beq $t1, $0, finish

        li  $v0, 1          #only in the loop for debug purposes
        add $a0, $t1, $0
        syscall

        add $t6, $t5, $0
        sw  $t4, 0($s0)
        sw  $t6, 0($t3)

        sub $s2, $s2, 4
        add $t3, $s2, $s0
        add $s0, $s0, 4
        j   swap
    finish:

        add $v1, $s0, $0
        jr  $ra
```

Let's say I enter these numbers into my array:

```
3 6 9 12 15 18
```

What I get is:

```
18 15 9 12 6 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The exit condition for your loop seems to be that the first *element* is greater than the second, which isn't right if you're trying to reverse the array (you should be comparing addresses or inidices). Your way of updating `$t3` also looks odd.

Here's a working loop:

```
swap:
    lw  $t5, 0($s0)
    lw  $t4, 0($t3)     #stores the element of last index into $t4

    sw  $t4, 0($s0)
    sw  $t5, 0($t3)

    sub $t3, $t3, 4
    add $s0, $s0, 4
    sle $t1,$t3,$s0
    beq $t1,$0,swap    # repeat until $t3 <= $s0
```

Comment: That completely works for reversing using indices.  I was instructed to compare the elements, and if the element in $s0 is less than the element in $t3 then I'm supposed to swap.

Comment: That makes no sense. What if the array was `18 6 9 12 15 3` ?  Then the function would not do anything, because it would break out of the loop on the very first iteration. Are you sure the task wasn't to sort the array, rather than reverse it?

Comment: Nevermind.  Apparently I misinterpreted the instructions.  The instructions stated "head = first index, tail = last index.  if (head <= tail)...."  I've been thinking I needed to "sort" the array, which would be dependent on the element.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  Had I truly paid attention to the instructions I would have realized my error instead of chasing my butt.